# Where is app.html.eex layout specified in Phoenix?

Tags: phoenix-framework

The default Phoenix project has `app.html.eex` and `root.html.leex`. In the routing file, I see `plug :put_root_layout, {RoveWeb.LayoutView, :root}` which specifies the root layout. However, I don't see anything similar for the `app.html.eex` layout. Is that explicitly defined anywhere, or is there a Phoenix default which automatically renders `app.html.eex` as a layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, app.html.eex is the default application layout when you're not using LiveView.

More info [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/live-layouts.html)

Answer (score 0):

See https://elixirforum.com/t/where-the-default-layout-of-views-app-html-eex-is-defined/29580/1

Note that you can use `Phoenix.Controller.put_layout/2` to control the app layout that is used for HTML files, juste like you use `Phoenix.Controller.put_root_layout/2`.

For example, we will render the file `layouts/login.html.heex` for the root layout but we won't use an app layout for HTML.

```
def new(conn, _params) do
  conn
  |> put_root_layout({MaintenanceWeb.Layouts, :login})
  |> put_layout(html: false)
  |> render(:new, error_message: nil)
end
```

It is of course usable in a plug pipeline.